# How to determine if a Windows OS font would support bold or italic

Tags: fonts, coding-style, flex4, embed, detect

How do you determine if a particular font supports bold or italic regardless whether it's a True Type or Type 1?  I have the following scenarios relating to embedding a Flex font issue:

- I have 3 TTF font files called Unknown1, Unknown2 and Unknown3.  Let's say they're installed for now
- When I embed the fonts, Flex tells me that Unknown2.ttf doesn't support a bold weight or Unknown3.ttf doesn't support an italic style

My question is, how did Flex knew all of that?  I've been searching through C# and Java libraries but none of them seem to offer what I need.  Or apparently, I'm not looking hard enough.  Anyways, are there classes in Java or C# that can provide me with some signature like:

Font unknownFont = Font.getFontFromAnyDirectory("Unknown2.ttf");
unknownFont.supportsAnyStyleCalled(Font.BOLD);//Returns false.
unknownFont.supportsAnyStyleCalled(Font.ITALIC);//Returns true.
//
unknownFont = Font.getFontFromAnyDirectory("Unknown3.ttf");
unknownFont.supportsAnyStyleCalled(Font.BOLD);//Returns true. unknownFont.supportsAnyStyleCalled(Font.ITALIC);//Returns false.

Answer (score 0):

in C# you can do it by invoking [FontFamily.IsStyleAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.isstyleavailable.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this one.  However, I've already tried it and it seems to give the available styles based on the family and not per font file.  Even though the variable is pointing to a specific Arial font file such as ariali.ttf or arialbd.ttf, it still gave all the available styles because it belonged to the Arial family.  And the Arial family consists of arial, arialbd, ariali, arialbi font files.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is pretty old, I had the same problem and the solution is stated in [C# get font style from .ttf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254973/c-sharp-get-font-style-from-ttf).

You can use:

```
GlyphTypeface ttf = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\calibrii.ttf"));
Debug.Print(ttf.Style.ToString()); //=Italic or Normal
Debug.Print(ttf.Weight.ToString()); //=Bold or Normal
```