# C# get font style from .ttf

Tags: c#, fonts

I write at the moment a programm that search all .ttf file's from the `C:\Windows\WinSxS` dictonary and copy them to another dictonary (I think I dont have to post some code here, because its working well).

Now the problem. As example the font `arial` is saved with the name `arial.ttf`, but this file exists more than 1 time with the same name. Now I found this link here: [get font name of ttf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885259/get-font-name-of-ttf-file), but the output name is still the same (always `arial`). I think the difference between these file is the `fontstyle` (italic, bold, ...), but how can I get the fontstyle of each `*.ttf` file?

Answer (score 2):

You need a reference to PresentationCore.
With that you can use GlyphTypeface to check for Style and Weight:
Example:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

GlyphTypeface ttf = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\calibrii.ttf"));
Debug.Print(ttf.Style.ToString()); //=Italic or Normal
Debug.Print(ttf.Weight.ToString()); //=Bold or Normal
```

Will not work with Postscript OTF though.

Edit: Credits to [C# lib for processing font files - TTF (TrueType), others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628247/c-sharp-lib-for-processing-font-files-ttf-truetype-others)